# How to share simple beans between activities?

Tags: java, android, javabeans

I have a a simple Java bean that gets filled in my second activity.
When I return back to my first activity(main activity) I want to have access to this data. But so far I have no idea how to do it.

Can anyone provide me with a code example of how to pass beans between Activities?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Shared Preferences if you have string data

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

Singleton class if you have objects to pass around.

If you want guaranteed persistance use database.